# virtual display in pure c. X11/xlib.h

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I am working with an image taken from a virtual display.
Is it possible to somehow get the pixel data in the `RGBRGBRGB` format in the data array of the image structure.... that is, only 3 components, not 4?
My goal is to optimize this function so that it doesn't use too much CPU.
Here is the function code

```
void func(struct data *img_packets)
{
    Display *Display = XOpenDisplay(display);
    if(!Display)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"%s",strerror(errno));
    }
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(Display);

    XWindowAttributes attributes;
    XGetWindowAttributes(Display, root, &attributes);
    while(1)
    {
        XImage *image = XGetImage(Display, root, 0, 0, display_width, display_height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
        for(int i=1;i<display_height+1;i++)
        {
            int j=header_size;
            for(int w=image->bytes_per_line*(i-1);w<=image->bytes_per_line*(i)-1;w+=4)
            {
                img_packets[i].arr[j+2] = image->data[w+2];//red
                img_packets[i].arr[j+1] = image->data[w+1];//green
                img_packets[i].arr[j+0] = image->data[w+0];//blue
                j+=3;
            }

        }
        XDestroyImage(image);
    }
    XCloseDisplay(Display);
}
```

Tried searching the internet for an answer but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Why do you want the format with only 3 components and not 4? Are you sure it would be faster? I doubt it, since 4 is a power of 2 and that may leave more room for optimization. Why not make both arrays with 4 components and use the, highly optimized, `memcpy()`? Or why do you copy it in the first place?

Comment: I send the resulting image to a special device that receives the image in RGB format, so I need 3 components

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the special device driver to accept RGB + Padding? It isn't very likely that you can change Xorg to return RGB (but i don't know).

Comment: I cannot change the driver.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://github.com/sulmone/X11/blob/master/libX11-1.5.0/src/GetImage.c Maybe this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Is there a reason that you use Xlib and not XCB? XCB is potentially faster because it is asynchron. maybe you could use xcb_get_image instead? (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libxcb-doc/xcb_get_image.3)

Comment: Using xcb offloaded the CPU a bit, but still can't get what I want. Apparently, I need to look for other possibilities for unloading the CPU in the program. Thanks for answers.

Comment: The GPU is designed to do such tasks very fast, but i doubt it will be faster overall since you need to pass the data to the GPU and back which is probably no worth it for this. You could try using openCL or something. Other question, does it have to come from the X-Server? Depending on the GPU you may can get it more directly.